# Flagging a suspected off-topic question "protected" by a bounty

Tags: discussion, support, bounty, scope

I don't quite understand why my custom flag on [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22811526/exporting-pivot-table-in-ms-access-to-excel-with-c-sharp) has been declined.

Flag:

[image]

Here's the link to [this Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties) which I have linked to in my flag as a supportive reference.

I don't want to get into an argument but very honestly, would like more explanation on why I shouldn't have flagged this question in first place. Any constructive critique is welcome..

Ps. *If interested, check out the [other questions with bounties by that user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670729/mana?tab=bounties)*.

Ps2. I realize this bounty is quite recent, the question's lifetime is longer and it has not gotten closed before the bounty was put on. So, please avoid a discussion about it.

---

UPDATE: *a hilarious comment by the OP*

[image]

Comment: You may want to explain *why* you feel the question is off-topic. To the moderator, I mean.

Comment: The moderator is saying that he doesn't think the question should be closed, not that it's not right to flag bountied questions that you think should be closed.

Comment: It isn't off-topic. It is about programming - the OP wants to write code to solve the problem. Yes, it is low quality, yes, it shows no effort. But it **is** on topic.

Comment: IMO too broad would be a perfectly valid reason to close. Without any example code or at bare minimum a "I've tried with X but it didn't work" the OPs biggest problem might be that he doesn't know how to compile or run any code we might give.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was declined because there's no reason to close the post. It's on topic. It's about using C# to export a Pivot table. That's about as 'on topic' as it gets.

It's a poor question because of its content -- but it is on topic.

Your flag reason:

> I am flagging this question because it is off-topic and should be closed. According to this Meta post the bounty should be refunded to the OP and question should be immediately closed.

was declined because of that.

It's a rather poor question, and needs fixing, but that's another matter.

Comment: I'm a little confused.  If it's on-topic (i.e. it doesn't meet the standards for closing), then it should stay open, yes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm an 'old school' on and off topic sort of guy; this newfangled, "Off topic because x" still takes getting used to. What I'd really like to say is, "Downvote to oblivion", but I can't say that, can I?

Comment: Then I'll say it for you. :)

Comment: I would expect this to be closed as 'minimal understanding' or 'too broad', like the 5 million other questions of genre 'how can I do X' each day. How does this differ?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: "Minimal understanding" doesn't exist anymore.  Too many people were abusing it as "minimal effort."

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If the question is "too broad" then it should be flagged saying that it's too broad, not off topic.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Sorry, I meant 'lacks sufficient information' (which I think is an appropriate substitute for it in this case).

Comment: It's not too broad, it's not unclear, and it doesn't lack sufficient information.  It's `icanhazcodez`, but we don't have a close reason for that.  Personally, I prefer `icanhazcodez` questions (which could help others) to 'Code dump, how fix" questions, which will never benefit anyone else.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel But it doesn't lack sufficient information.  It explains what he wants to do in sufficient detail to be able to answer it.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not disputing that at all, but I'm getting some vibes that the question should stay open while I would think it should get closed for the beforementioned reasons.

Comment: Wouldn't an answer require an entire introduction on how to do this with no attempt to go on? Sure, it says what it is he wants exactly but I've always known these questions to get closed.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You're saying that you wish you could close it, even though the close reasons you want to use don't apply to that answer at all.  When you want to close a question, but none of the close reasons apply, then it generally means that the question shouldn't be closed.  Choosing the vaguest close reason to abuse and use anyway is harmful, and why so many otherwise good close reasons have had to be removed.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel If you feel that an answer to a question would require an answer well beyond what can be posted in an SO answer, due to its shear scope, then that would be an acceptable reason to close it as "too broad".

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: An extended explanation wouldn't be required; the question is answerable with a code snippet, and perhaps some brief comments about how the code snippet works.

Comment: I was under the assumption that questions that just ask for code were supposed to be closed. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I should have mentioned that IMO the question is too broad. If it is too broad and we have a close reason for it than it makes it off-topic - like any other question on site that is about programming but shows no research etc. There is no attempt at solving it whatsoever...I accept this answer just to have the question "solved" and not attract more attention but in the end I still disagree the question is on-topic. What IMO makes it off topic is the fact that it could potentially be closed as too broad. [**no 3. is inaccurate then**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: How many more questions are going to be brought about as a result of the ambiguity of the term "off-topic" as far as SE is concerned? Do you people like having these endless arguments all the time?

Comment: @BoltClock: I thought the improvements to the off topic reasons helps a lot in the decision making. As soon as you provide an "Other" reason, people are going to want to fill out what they want.