# How to deal with a good problem, but a bad question - with a bounty bribe!

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

*TL;DR*

1. Are "Help me make this code work!" questions allowed?
2. Can we downvote the Bounty awards that look like bribes, but not the question?

---

**Note: A part of this is covered in [How can I close a question that has an active bounty?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/very-broad-question-but-with-a-bounty-what-to-do)**

With reference to 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333958/unable-to-print-specific-ouputs-in-specific-divs', the problem is clearly a good one that many people might be interested in.

A look at the question, however, shows not a great understanding of the problem. Specifically, the part of the code that sends the request, and the part of the code that populates the div alone is sufficient. It's quite a task to go through the Wall Of Code and make sense of it.

The OP wants to award a bounty to:

> [...]that user who can help me to modify my program to facebook like multi
>   client chat.

My question is twofold, and it *is* opinion based:

1. My understanding is that SO is meant to be a problem-solution site that can help the community as a whole. Are 'Help make this work!' types useful? How will a new coder facing the problem ever find this? Or is the community expected to clean up the question and make it easier to find + answer (which is what we do many times).
2. *Opinion based* Aren't questions like this, where bounty is used as a bribe to get people to answer despite a lack of effort, harmful for the site? Seeing as adding a bounty seems to be willful circumvention of rules to ensure site integrity, can we look at this as something worthy of additional penalty?

---

Feature proposal - Can we have a downvote for bounty specifically for when the community feels that bounty is being used as encouragement to answer not-very-useful stuff? In other words, **Can we Downvote the usage of Bounty?**

Comment: This is an interesting point of view. To go further, maybe the possibility to open a bounty should be reviewed by trusted users first. So the OP starts a bounty, and this bounty is only public once it gets enough votes.

Comment: Thanks @gnat. I've still not got the hang of searching for questions, clearly! I will edit to reflect that one part is addressed by the prev Q

Comment: also related [Flagging a suspected off-topic question “protected” by a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252539/flagging-a-suspected-off-topic-question-protected-by-a-bounty)

Answer (score 3):

Concur that there are quite a few apparently off-topic (non-programming, too broad, subjective, etc) questions with bounties:

- [VMware - guest cannot access server on host (bridged network)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22958075/vmware-guest-cannot-access-server-on-host-bridged-network)
- [Architecture for a complete application with Push for browser and native applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23410079/architecture-for-a-complete-application-with-push-for-browser-and-native-applica)
- [Prevent Google Glass from Auto-Uploading Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644764/prevent-google-glass-from-auto-uploading-photos)
- [How to stream audio from one Android device to another Android device Via Bluetooth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789394/how-to-stream-audio-from-one-android-device-to-another-android-device-via-blueto)
- [Video Surveliance application by connecting DVR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472648/video-surveliance-application-by-connecting-dvr)
- [How can I set up connection with DVR and decode the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037422/how-can-i-set-up-connection-with-dvr-and-decode-the-data)
- [Server push notification implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466637/server-push-notification-implementation)

But maybe not enough to justify developing special handling means.

Comment: Shouldn't we catch it before it becomes a problem, and a easy way to game SO into a mechanical trunk? Also, acting quicker may avoid "But it's been like this and it works!" upheavals :)

Comment: mechanical trunk?

Comment: [Amazon Mechanical Trunk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome) is a crowdsourcing Internet marketplace that enables individuals or businesses (known as Requesters) to co-ordinate the use of human intelligence to perform tasks that computers are currently unable to do - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk)

Comment: @Sharadh: Mechanical *Turk*, not Trunk.