# Bounty on a question of questionable quality

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, bounty, question-quality

There is [a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851737/computing-nearest-vertex-neighbors-in-a-dag-completed-by-transitive-closure) that isn't specifically about programming -- it's about algorithms. I think that it's not a good question for SO (although I may be wrong, but that isn't relevant here), so I want to flag it for moderator attention so that someone more experienced can decide the issue. However, I immediately got a message telling me that questions with an active bounty can't be closed.

So, my question to you, is why can't I flag this question?

I realize that promoting bounties *seems* to be important to some people (though I can't for the life of my understand why), and I can accept that. However, it seems that simply adding a bounty to a question protects it. If this is right, then it seems a quite dangerous policy.

Comment: what's dangerous about that?

Comment: You do know that software algorithms are explicitly listed in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Btw, algorithms are on-topic for SO. There's even a tag for it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algorithm

Comment: If you got a message about closing questions from the `flag` link, than that's probably a bug.  flagging and closing are different kinds of actions

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I wasn't specifically asking about my decision to flag -- I realise that it's questionable in and of itself. I was asking why that decision has been taken away from me?

Comment: Whenever I see a question with a bounty that should be closed, I flag it because we can't vote to close them while the bounty is on. Never had a problem raising a flag.

Comment: @SamIam Some ago, we were joking in chat about a competition to see who could post the worst question that stays open long enough to be bountied.

Comment: @SamIam You can't cast a "recommend closure" flag on a bountied question as you run into the same problem. You'd have to cast an "other" flag and explain.

Comment: @SamIam -- dangerous because if it were not possible to flag or close a bountied question then evil f*kers could post bile filled hateful crap here and the community could not remove it.

Comment: @Mysticial - I don't actually think that this is an algorithmic question, even though it's been posed as one (sort of). I think it's a question that happens to have algorithmic solutions but which could possibly be answered quicker and more accurately on a maths site.

Comment: @EngineerDollery `deletion` is **also** a different action than `closing`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flagging a suspected off-topic question "protected" by a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252539/flagging-a-suspected-off-topic-question-protected-by-a-bounty) and of [Very broad question but with a bounty, what to do?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252192/very-broad-question-but-with-a-bounty-what-to-do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use a close vote or close flag against a question with a bounty (for reasons that I'm too tired to look up now), but you can use other types of flags on these questions.

If you come across a very clearly off topic or otherwise terrible question that is entirely being propped up by a bounty, you can use an "other" flag and describe why the bounty should be removed so the question could be closed. Moderators have the ability to refund bounties and make the question able to be closed again.

However, I should caution that we only do this in the most obvious of cases, and when the bounty was issued also plays into this. If the question is borderline or otherwise wouldn't be something I'd immediately close on sight, I tend to let the bounty run its course and have the community vote on it after that. Similarly, if a bounty has existed on a question for more than a day or so, and people have started answering the question as a result of the bounty being there, I become even more hesitant to remove it.

So yes, we can deal with people using bounties to game the close system if you use an "other" flag to warn us, but it needs to be a clear case of that before we step in. Spam and offensive flags are also viable against a bountied question, but I don't know that I've ever seen a justified one of those cast against such a question.

Comment: The problem with this is that Other flags sometimes get really slow response times on SO. I've flagged [a question with a fresh bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371582/why-is-my-website-cutting-off-on-mobile-devices) two weeks ago. Since then, the question got swiftly answered, the bounty was awarded, and I can vote to close now (after the fact), and my flag is _still_ active.

Comment: It's possibly worth mentioning that if you encounter a question with a bounty which is on topic but should be closed for other reasons, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794512/is-it-possible-for-two-branches-to-conflict-on-a-file-when-one-branch-doesnt-ev), you can just [downvote it telling the author why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794512/is-it-possible-for-two-branches-to-conflict-on-a-file-when-one-branch-doesnt-ev#comment36834440_23794512). After all: A bounty isn't a replacement for providing a a good question.

Comment: [Allow users to vote to close bountied questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121448/allow-users-to-vote-to-close-bountied-questions) might be the question you were thinking off. [Shog mentions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137432/182513) that he generally supports the idea but doesn't feel the needed complexity is justified given the supposedly "rare" occurrence.

Comment: @JanDvorak - To be honest, we triage these flags in order of importance and have been lightly staffed recently due to vacations, etc. I didn't see an immediate need to remove that bounty and close the question, so I moved on to other higher-priority items. Now the question can be voted on by the community.