# How can we discourage low quality answers to bounty questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

Bounty questions: some people love them, most people hate them.  Personally, I love bounty hunting on the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tags.  But I've started to notice a pattern with low and medium rep users: many are attracted by the idea of quick rep gain and post low quality, link-only answers.

Exhibit A:

[image: LQ Answer]

This is the epitome of a link-only answer, and it makes me sad to se even a 500+ rep user quickly post a link to a library or GitHub project in an attempt to win the bounty.

Exhibit B:

[iOS linkedin authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28491280/2415822)

In an attempt to clean up iOS LinkedIn API questions, a bounty was placed on a low-quality question to attract a canonical response.  This then attracted a bunch of link-only answers while I was writing a canonical:

[image: Long list of trash]

I understand 15k+ users can protect questions as they see fit, and questions are automatically protected after a certain number of answer from low rep users are deleted, but does the community think with the additional attention bounty questions get that an additional layer of protection should be added to them?  How can we discourage (or even prevent) low quality answers to bounty questions?

Comment: How about downvoting these answers?

Comment: @Gothdo a great suggestion (which I try to do with a comment if one has not been posted already).  I guess my goal is how do we fix this before the answers are even posted, which might not even be possible.

Comment: Why should bounty questions be treated specially?  The quality filters should apply equally to all questions and we should not get these poor answers on any question.  In the absence of better filters down/comment/delete vote/flag(when appropriate)

Comment: @NathanOliver bounty questions are already treated specially.  If they fall through the cracks of community moderation, they are immune to closure without moderator intervention.

Comment: Bounties get more answers,as per their very nature. Answers CAN (And statistically a good portion are) be bad.... More answers = more bad answers. I don't see a benefit in making bounty answers special in that regards. As long as bounty = more rep than the usual amount, you'll get people trying to go in for a quick win

Comment: Yes but why should the answers be held to a different standard?  If we do not like link only answers then that is site wide.  We should not have the filter just set for questions that have a bounty on them.

Comment: @NathanOliver Bounty questions are *already* treated specially. They get visibility. They cannot be closed. We could do away with the whole thing or we could maybe decide that they need to be special in other ways. (I'd rather get rid of them myself, but I'm sure my opinion is not the dominant one.) Them being treated specially is a factor in why they are low quality answer magnets in ways regular questions aren't. I see too many folks playing the "throw answer at bountied question" lottery.

Comment: @Louis while true, if we can make a smart filter to stop link only answers on bounties... Wouldn't it make sense to make that filter site wide? I think that's where Nathan was going with this. Any feature that can minimize bad answers on bounties should be done site wide instead of just on bounties (unless the feature involves something specific to bounties)

Comment: @Patrice Exactly.  Anything to filter out the crud should not just be used for questions with bounties on them.  It should be site wide.

Comment: link-only answers, lucky you. Means you can vote down, flag and simply wait for rep refund after your flag is handled and answer is deleted. Worse when garbage posters add "just enough" hand-waving to make their stuff ineligible for flagging. You vote down 4...5...10 answers knowing full well that not only there will be no rep refund but that the garbage will be voted up by some lemming passer by ["for balance"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/839601)

Comment: well, we could just... not offer bounties.

Comment: @KevinB that's a different discussion. I wonder if there is an existing meta about removing the bounty system entirely.  I know shog has come out against them.

Comment: Everybody goes a little nutso when the normal Q+A process failed and the lottery started.  And not infrequently on [an incredibly poor question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28491280/17034) that fits just about any answer.  Even hi-rep users that [insist such a question should not be answered](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331723/17034).  Follow your own advice and some odds that it will be followed by example.

Comment: @HansPassant I have given up on flagging bounty questions due to the latency between when the flag is raised compared to when it is actually handled.  If I don't answer the question, someone else will and reap the benefits.  And there is conflicting information on when bounty questions should actually be closed.  See [Are bounty questions that are too broad exempt from closure if they have good answers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/325581/2415822).

Comment: @HansPassant and as the [top bounty earner on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158342/top-200-bounty-earners) you're telling me all of your answers have been on "perfect" bounty questions?  I doubt it.

Comment: I doubt it as well.  It is you that is complaining about this, not me.  Strongly disliking somebody else to "reap the benefits" is a strange motivation to answer a very poor question but, hey, if that's okay for you then it is okay for everybody else that posted to that bounty.

Comment: @HansPassant You're right.  If I feel so strongly about this, I should stop answering bad bounty questions and keep flagging.  The idea that if I let someone else answer and they get 50 free rep is really dumb for me to get hung up on.  I mean, it doesn't even matter...  Everything is made up and the points don't matter.

Comment: I think the thing that tripped me up about that LinkedIn questions was that I knew the user who put the bounty on it from chat, since they wanted a canonical to close a bunch of dupes.  Just because I know the user who added the bounty doesn't make the question more or less acceptable.  I can't flag some questions and answer others just because I feel like it, it makes me look like a hypocrite.  Which you @HansPassant have pointed out.

Answer (score 14):

Bounties are only awarded under two conditions:

- The bounty offerer *chooses* an answer, and awards full bounty; or
- The system chooses an answer based on votes, and awards half bounty.

There isn't all that much we can do about the former since it's whomever's choice to give upvotes/accept marks/bounties to terrible answers, but it doesn't mean that we shouldn't downvote it *anyway*; just in case the offerer doesn't come back to manually award the bounty, it means that it will have a harder time going to a terrible answer.

Comment: ... it'll also make fraud detection that much easier for everyone :^)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Part of the reason why I asked this question is because I wasn't sure if the community thought that this was something that needed addressing, or if there was anything that could be done about it.  Personally, I don't have a great answer (to crap on bounty questions or on the site in general).  I like to focus on bounty questions since they get more attention, but a lot of users would probably argue that bounty questions are no different than regular questions, and should be moderated the same way.

Comment: They should be moderated the same way, yes, but... we're restricted in doing so. (can't vote to close/delete without moderator help)

Comment: @JAL It would be interesting if answers with a negative vote lost some extra points when the bounty was allocated.