# How to handle VLQ posts that were awarded bounties

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

The answer I had in mind is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447108/null-key-argument-error/3510431#3510431).

**Edit:** Since the post was since deleted, here's the screenshot for us lesser mortals with less than 10K reputation:
[image]

The answer is mostly a link, so normally I would just vote to delete it, but it has 3 upvotes and was given a 175-point bounty.

Also, out of curiosity, what happens if an answer that was awarded a bounty is deleted? Does the person who received the bounty get to keep the reputation, even though the answer was deleted? Does the original awarder of the bounty get the reputation back?

Comment: Nothing would happen. This post is old and has a score of 3, so they're eligible to keep the reputation if it's deleted. The original bounty is only given back to its creator if the entire question is deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can we discourage low quality answers to bounty questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334699/how-can-we-discourage-low-quality-answers-to-bounty-questions)

Comment: @suraj It's a somewhat different situation - in this case, the bounty was *actually awarded* to a VLQ answer. I'm not sure if it was just a case of someone posting a VLQ answer to try for the bounty. My question isn't so much how to prevent that kind of situation from happening in the first place as it is about what to do now that it actually occurred.

Comment: @EJoshuaS ok.. It is slightly different.. But the answer by Makoto there addresses this situation as well so It is a related question..

Comment: It was auto awarded rather than being given specifically. It was half of a 350 bounty.

Comment: The answer seems to have been deleted in the meantime.

Comment: @Justastudent: Indeed, a ♦ mod deleted it about 6 hours after this meta question was asked.

Comment: @Justastudent I edited to include an image of the question for the benefit of those of us with less than 10K reputation