# Are questions about Android AOSP acceptable on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently I have encountered a few questions on Stack Overflow which are related to Android, but not related to general programming. They are rather related to errors which are linked with the Android Open Source Project, i.e. creating own custom ROM for Android Devices. What I think is that these kind of question usually "should be asked" on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/), rather than on Stack Overflow.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301329/cant-build-recovery-image-with-aosp-4-2-2) is an example of such a question.

So should there be any action taken on these posts?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should flag/vote to close them as off-topic. The standard reason

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

might be confusing because it mentions Super User. That can be mitigated by posting a comment directing the OP to Android SE.

Another, probably better, option is to use the 'Other' off-topic close reason, e.g.

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. General questions about Android should be asked on [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

If that option is not available to you, you could use the 'Blatantly off-topic' reason and manually post the comment above.

Comment: I can't see a custom off-topic flag.

Comment: The option is called 'Other', it's at the bottom of the off-topic reasons.

Comment: I don't have that. It may be for high rep users

Comment: Ah, you're right. You'll need 3000 reputation for that.

Comment: So what will be suitable category for me ?

Comment: Both are fine, as long as you indicate in the comment that the question belongs on Android SE.

Comment: I can't vote to close as that question has an open bounty with it

Comment: Then, [flag for moderator attention](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252539/flagging-a-suspected-off-topic-question-protected-by-a-bounty).

Comment: Well I flagged it as said by you but it was declined by Moderator saying no evidence found to support it.